# Global Windows Key Press

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a simple WPF application and I need to capture F1 key pressed in Windows (Operation System), even if my WPF window is minimized, or it isn't activated.

I have problems with detecting this. I searched on Internet and I found many results, but they didn't helped me.

For detecting a key pressed inside of application I used this simple code:

```
AddHandler(Keyboard.KeyDownEvent, (KeyEventHandler)KeyPressed);
private void KeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Key == Key.F1)
      {
           //my code went here
      }
}
```

But this doesn't work when my window isn't activated.

So, my question is: **how to detect global key press?**

I repeat: It is a WPF application.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No need to `Keyboard Hooking`. Just use [`RegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx) (Defines a system-wide hot key) and [`UnregisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646327.aspx) from Windows API. Try using these in C# from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/registerhotkey.html) or these tutorials:

- [Global Hotkeys: Register a hotkey that is triggered even when form isn't focused.](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/)
- [Simple steps to enable Hotkey and ShortcutInput user control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5914/Simple-steps-to-enable-Hotkey-and-ShortcutInput-us)

There is a sample in [Microsoft Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/87d66b1c-330c-42fe-8a40-81f82012575c).

You can use these modifiers and [Virtual-Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731.aspx):

```
MOD_ALT      (0x0001)
MOD_CONTROL  (0x0002)
MOD_NOREPEAT (0x4000)
MOD_SHIFT    (0x0004)
MOD_WIN      (0x0008)
```

for example F1 key is `VK_F1 (0x70)`.

Comment: What a pleasant surprise. For once I come to a global hotkey thread and the top answer is `RegisterHotKey` and not `SetWindowsHookEx`.

Comment: I had errors on Windows 10 using the `MOD_WIN` modifier key.  Windows may no longer allow you to hook with that modifier.

Answer (score 0):

When your application is not in focus - messags pump will not get anything - you need to use system level API's for hooking keys. (try to search info on SetWindowsHookEx)