# Killing a started process on keypress/buttonpress while process has focus

Tags: c#, process, kill

I have a program which is meant to launch other programs with launch arguments. I would like to be able to kill these processes on a keypress or buttonpress from a controller, but my program does/would not have focus when the key/button is pressed(The launched process does). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global Windows Key Press](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752254/global-windows-key-press)

Comment: @Preston Guillot I updated my Question to be more specific. The global keypress is helpful for part of my problem, but Ideally, I want my program to still "Hear" all input from keyboards and other HID devices (such as usb gamepads)

Comment: There are a couple of dupes of that question as well, which both link out to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx, where the author also provides similar code for hooking into mouse events in the comments. Globally monitoring all input is going to start making your application suspiciously look like mal-ware, fwiw.

Comment: I may end up just using Joy2Key and mapping that key/button to Alt-F4 then, if this is so much hassle. The program is honestly just something I am making for myself